# How to hide the first picklist from a dependent picklist on a screen flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist, screen-flow, visibility, flow-screen-component

I use the dependent picklist component in a screen flow. I only require the user to input the value of the second picklist (child), they should not be able to change (if possible not even see) the value of the first picklist (parent).

My problem is that both the parent and the child picklist have large numbers of values and will probably change quite often, so it would not be feasible to use multiple "normal" picklist components and then decide via the visibility condition which one is being shown to the user.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.